Is there a way to define a function over the complex numbers, that satisfies a log property?
Is it possible to prove that the only continuous function over $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ that satisfies
(1) $f(z_1 \cdot z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$
must be the function $f(z)=0$?
Is it true when $f$ is holomorphic?
I think that when $f$ is holomorphic due to the identity thorem, but I am not sure about it.
Update: it seems that the function
$f(r \cdot e^{i\theta})= \ln r$
satisfies the condition for a continuous function.
Now my question is about holomorphic functions.

(This first part is edited, the previous approach was not quite right.) The condition $f(z_1 \cdot z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$ implies that $f(x) = a \log (x)$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ (for some $a \in \mathbb{R})$. Indeed, this follows from the definition of the real logarithm and the fact that $f'(x)=f'(1)/x$ as shown by psl2Z (so $a=f'(1)$).
If $a$ were nonzero, then the identity theorem implies that $f$ agrees with a branch of the complex logarithm, say the one on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$. But it is well-known that this branch cannot be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0\}$, contradiction. So we must have $a=0$.

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $f(z_1z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$ for all $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.
Take the derivative w.r.t. $z_1$. It follows $cf'(cz) = f'(z)$ for all $z,c \neq 0$. In particular with $c = \frac{1}{z}$ it holds $\frac{f'(1)}{z} = f'(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Integrate over the circle
$$0=\int_{|z| = 1} f'(z)dz = \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{f'(1)}{z}dz = f'(1)2\pi i$$
Therefore $f'(1) = 0$ and thus $0 = \frac{f'(1)}{z} = f'(z)$ for all $z \neq 0$. So, $f=C$ is constant. Now, $C = f(z_1z_2) = f(z_1)+ f(z_2) = C + C = 2C$, so $C = 0$, therefore $f=C=0$.

Nice and elegant solution :)

@psl2Z: I really like this solution but I don't think I understand a particular step, can you explain it, please? If I understand correctly, you are differentiating w.r.t. $z_1$ and so $z_2$ is constant in the derivative, hence $z_2f'(z_1z_2)=f'(z_1)$ and you put $c=z_2$. Then you rename $z$ the variable $z_1$. But, if $c$ is constant, how can it equals a variable quantity like $1/z$? Maybe you used $c$ just to understate the fact that it is constant only in the context of differentiation?

@Frieren You might prefer to skip that step; given that $z_2f'(z_1 z_2) = f'(z_1)$ holds for arbitrary (nonzero) $z_1$ and $z_2$, it holds for any two values satisfying $z_1 z_2 = 1$.
